# PublicClientApplicationBuilder and TokenCacheHelper

Tags: c#, azure-ad-msal

I am getting confused. I recently upgraded my Microsoft Graph and associated Nuget packages and they had some breaking changes for MSAL v3.

I have seen this [article](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki/token-cache-serialization) and added the following to my `TokenCacheHelp` class so that it now looks like:

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//
// Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.
// All rights reserved.
//
// This code is licensed under the MIT License.
//
// Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy
// of this software and associated documentation files(the "Software"), to deal
// in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights
// to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and / or sell
// copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is
// furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions :
//
// The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in
// all copies or substantial portions of the Software.
//
// THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
// IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
// FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT.IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
// AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
// LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM,
// OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN
// THE SOFTWARE.
//
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

using System.IO;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using Microsoft.Identity.Client;

    namespace OutlookCalIFConsole
    {
        static class TokenCacheHelper
        {
     
            /// <summary>
            /// Get the user token cache
            /// </summary>
            /// <returns></returns>
            public static TokenCache GetUserCache()
            {
                if (usertokenCache == null)
                {
                    usertokenCache = new TokenCache();
                    usertokenCache.SetBeforeAccess(BeforeAccessNotification);
                    usertokenCache.SetAfterAccess(AfterAccessNotification);
                }
                return usertokenCache;
            }
    
            static TokenCache usertokenCache;
    
            /// <summary>
            /// Path to the token cache
            /// </summary>
            public static string CacheFilePath = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location + "msalcache.txt";
    
            private static readonly object FileLock = new object();
    
            public static void EnableSerialization(ITokenCache tokenCache)
            {
                tokenCache.SetBeforeAccess(BeforeAccessNotification);
                tokenCache.SetAfterAccess(AfterAccessNotification);
            }
    
            public static void BeforeAccessNotification(TokenCacheNotificationArgs args)
            {
                lock (FileLock)
                {
                    //args.TokenCache.Deserialize(File.Exists(CacheFilePath)
                    //    ? File.ReadAllBytes(CacheFilePath)
                    //    : null);
    
                    // See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-net-token-cache-serialization
                    args.TokenCache.DeserializeMsalV3(File.Exists(CacheFilePath)
                            ? ProtectedData.Unprotect(File.ReadAllBytes(CacheFilePath),
                                       null,
                                       DataProtectionScope.CurrentUser)
                            : null);
                }
            }
    
            public static void AfterAccessNotification(TokenCacheNotificationArgs args)
            {
                // if the access operation resulted in a cache update
                if (args.HasStateChanged)
                {
                    lock (FileLock)
                    {
                        // reflect changes in the persistent store
                        //File.WriteAllBytes(CacheFilePath, args.TokenCache.Serialize());
                        // once the write operation takes place restore the HasStateChanged bit to false
                        //args.TokenCache.HasStateChanged = false;
    
                        // See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-net-token-cache-serialization
                        // reflect changes in the persistent store
                        File.WriteAllBytes(CacheFilePath,
                                  ProtectedData.Protect(args.TokenCache.SerializeMsalV3(),
                                                  null,
                                                  DataProtectionScope.CurrentUser)
                                  );
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

But thinks are not workign quite right. At the moment I have:

```
    IPublicClientApplication PublicClientApp = null;

    public Outlook()
    {
        TokenCacheHelper.CacheFilePath = Program.Options.TokenCachePath;
        //PublicClientApp = new PublicClientApplication(_AppID, "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common", TokenCacheHelper.GetUserCache());
        PublicClientApp = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create(_AppID).Build();
        TokenCacheHelper.EnableSerialization(TokenCacheHelper.GetUserCache());

    }
```

In the article it said to use `PublicClientApp.GetUserCache` but this value is empty. So I used `TokenCacheHelper.GetUserCache()` but it is not working. When I start the utility it shows the authorisation screen. But it will not cache this value anymore and keeps showing the authorisation screen.

What else must I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had to change to:

```
IPublicClientApplication PublicClientApp = null;

public Outlook()
{
    PublicClientApp = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create(_AppID).Build();
    TokenCacheHelper.EnableSerialization(PublicClientApp.UserTokenCache);

}
```

The key was removing the `TokenCacheHelper.CacheFilePath = Program.Options.TokenCachePath;` call. I noticed the article stated:

> **Important** MSAL.NET creates token caches for you and provides you with the `IToken` cache. Then, you read the caches using the application's `UserTokenCache` and `AppTokenCache` properties. You are not supposed to implement the interface yourself.

## Update

Actually, that was not the reason. This code is fine:

```
IPublicClientApplication PublicClientApp = null;

public Outlook()
{
    PublicClientApp = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create(_AppID).Build();
    TokenCacheHelper.CacheFilePath = Program.Options.TokenCachePath;
    TokenCacheHelper.EnableSerialization(PublicClientApp.UserTokenCache);
}
```

I had two issues:

1. I had some DLL library inconsistencies in the packages.
2. I had to delete the previous cache data file as it was not binary compatible.

I am able to specify my own path for the cache file and it uses it. It is working fine consistently for me and for my users.

### Update

For `Microsoft.Graph` 5.x I had to move some of my code into the new `TokenProvider` class but the concept is still the same.

Comment: You are right about the important note. On the current version of MSAL, you cant even extend `IToken`. You have to create your cache provider and hook it to MSAL cache (so MSAL knows where to store the cache). [Here are some good providers for reference](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/master/Microsoft.Identity.Web/TokenCacheProviders)

Comment: Brilliant. This is what happens when developers check-in build artifacts to their code repo's and other dev's pull it down and try to run on their local.

Comment: @JWeezy that's hard to detect. Really the only way to tell is to pull the repo to somewhere else ideally another computer and try to build.